# Error "Ambiguous use of subscript" when migrating to Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2

I just migrated my code from swift 1.2 to Swift 2 and I meet the error:

> Ambiguous use of subscript

on the line

> if((value["Success"] as! Int) == 1)

```
func selectorGetUpdateBuyer(notification:NSNotification)
    {
    if(self==notification.object as! BackProfilController)
        {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self,name:PixoNotificationCenter.PNC.AppixiaExchanges_to_FrontProfilController_getUpdateBuyer,object:nil)
            var succes:Bool=false
            for(key,value) in notification.userInfo as NSDictionary!
            {
                if(key as! String=="Result")
                {
                    if((value["Success"] as! Int) == 1)
                    {
                        succes=true
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Does any one has an idea of what I should correct to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not know the type of `value`.

You can use:

```
if(key as! String=="Result")
{
    if(((value as! NSDictionary)["Success"] as! Int) == 1)
    {
        succes=true
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow ! Thanks a lot for you anwer ! It works great !!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept the answer to close the question.